# Calling Method at runtime using some string

Tags: java

I am new to these and I need a solution or idea how I can do it

**I have the following code:**

```
if (page.getId().equals("STEP_NAME_SUBMIT_OTP_FOR_TRANSACTION"))
    emRequestResponse.setTagElementList(agent.getHeader().getTagElementList().getSTEP_NAME_SUBMIT_OTP_FOR_TRANSACTION());
else if (page.getId().equals("STEP_NAME_SUBMIT_CAPTCHA_FOR_LOGIN"))
    emRequestResponse.setTagElementList(agent.getHeader().getTagElementList().getSTEP_NAME_SUBMIT_CAPTCHA_FOR_LOGIN());
```

I need a better way to call the method at run time based on the id, so if the name is `STEP_NAME_SUBMIT_OTP_FOR_TRANSACTION` I need to call the method `getSTEP_NAME_SUBMIT_OTP_FOR_TRANSACTION` and so on.

Comment: what's wrong with the approach ?

Comment: There can be like 10 to 15 id's at run time and i don't want if else 15 times or switch , i need a way in which i just get a id and i call a method based on that id

Comment: Do all these `getXXX` methods return the same type? If so, what is that type?

Comment: yes all return the same type

Comment: @ArvindCarpenter you can try with my answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call method like below code:

```
try {
Method method = emRequestResponse.getDeclaredMethod("method name", parameterTypes);
method.invoke(objectToInvokeOn, params);
} catch(Exception ex) {
System.out.println(ex.toString());
}
```

Comment: in your case you have to pass below line to call getDeclaredMethod
emRequestResponse.setTagElementList(agent.getHeader().getTagElementList().geDeclaredMethod();

Comment: so parameter type is the type of parameter we pass to that method right, and if so in my case there is no parameters to be passed then i will leave it as null or void

Comment: @ArvindCarpenter You can skip paramaters , only pass method name.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `switch` over `if-else`, `switch` performs better than `if-else`.

Switch performance will be better as in case of switch there will be one time evaluation . Once it evaluated the switch it knows which case needs to be executed but in case of if else it has to go through all conditions in case of worst scenario.

In case of large number of conditions, better will be switch performance but for shorter list (just two conditions), it can be slower also

Comment: actually these id are generated at run time and corrosponding method is also generated at run time, so i don't know at starting position what will be the id's and hence i can not hard code these in switch case

Comment: in such case, if you know correlation between method name and parameter value you may use reflection api to invoke method

Comment: yes relation is if id is STEP_NAME_SUBMIT_OTP_FOR_TRANSACTION then the method name will be getSTEP_NAME_SUBMIT_OTP_FOR_TRANSACTION

Comment: i guess then you may use answer proposed by @Chetan Joshi below

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is the **REFLECTION API** of java.

I would recommend using `switch case` for your strings, because, as per your requirement, I see that the Strings can be made `final`.

And using the `Method` class, you can invoke methods by populating the method name and required arguments.

The following block of code should do the trick for you, assuming the methods you want to call are defined in a class named `TagElementsList`.

```
private List invokeMethod(TagElementsList tagElementsList, String pageId) {
    Method method = TagElementsList.class.getMethod("get"+pageId);
    List returnList = (TagElementsList)method.invoke(tagElementsList);
    return returnList;
}
```

You can thus get the method working as per your needs by invoking a call to the `invokeMethod` method from the required location in your code by the following call, considering the above method is declared in the same class as the point from where it has to be invoked. You can of course put define it in a different class and invoke a call to the method via an instance of that class too.

```
List list = invokeMethod(agent.getHeader().getTagElementList(), page.getid());
 emRequestResponse.setTagElementList(list);
```